Foursquare API - v3/places/search - No results
Issue with Foursquare v3/places/search API Returning Empty Results in Lisbon
Hi!
I've been using the v3/places/search API successfully, but since this morning, it has stopped returning results for some locations without any changes to my query parameters or headers.
Here is the API documentation.
Examples:

Lisbon, Portugal:

Previously working, now returns empty results.
Example URL:
https://api.foursquare.com/v3/places/search?ll=38.7441392%2C-9.2009353&radius=5000


Madrid, Spain (or other locations):

Works fine and returns results.
Example URL:
https://api.foursquare.com/v3/places/search?ll=40.4377968%2C-3.9913533&radius=5000



I also tried using the ne and sw bounding box parameters to cover all of Portugal, but still no results.
Additional Details:

Headers:

accept: application/json
Authorization: <api key>
Accept-Language: pt


Query Parameters:

fields: fsq_id,name,location,categories,distance,description,tel,website,email,social_media,hours,hours_popular,rating,stats,popularity,price,menu,photos,features
radius: <radius>
ll: <latitude,longitude>


I have many credits remaining, so it's not a credit issue.

Could this be related to a database change or a regional issue in Portugal?
It also can't be any rate limit, because it's only me testing this locally!
Any help would be appreciated!
